# Angular ng-click not working inside table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery jTable, which is being initalized with angularjs $document.ready function. Here the column with ng-click event in it:

```
            $document.ready(function () {
                jQuery('#tblArticlesSearch').jtable({              
                  paging: true
                 fields:{
                       ToCart: {
                          width: '1%',
                        display: function () {
                          return '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" 
                           aria-hidden="true" ng-click="AddToDeliveryList();"></i>';
                        }
                      }
                  }
               }
                });
              });
```

In controller, here is the function:

```
angular.module("deliveryListModule")
.controller("deliveryListController", ["$scope", "$http", "$document", function ($scope, $http, $document) {


  $scope.AddToDeliveryList = function () {
    alert("add");
  }
```

And of course, controller and module are applied on document:

```
<div id="divMain" class="divMain" ng-app="deliveryListModule"
        ng-controller="deliveryListController">
```

Problem is, that ng-click event is not firing when I click on the item. Nothing happens. Why is that?

**EDIT:**

With thanks to [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520245/angular-ng-click-not-working-inside-table-cell#comment68282301_40520245), I've used this line of code and it works fine now:

```
return $compile('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="AddToDeliveryList();"></i>')($scope);
```

Of course, I've also injected $compile.

Comment: [ng-click not working from dynamically generated HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19267979/2025923), [ng-click not working in dynamically created content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30468856/2025923), [Dynamically created element not firing click event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32649180/2025923)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468856/ng-click-not-working-in-dynamically-created-content

Comment: There's an extra closing bracket `}` in your `$document.ready(function ()`

Comment: @Tushar - thanks for you answer. I just don't understand one thing: what is HTML where I should append compiled element? Should I bind whole table with $scope or just one cell and where to append this?

Comment: Just use `return $compile('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" 
                           aria-hidden="true" ng-click="AddToDeliveryList();"></i>')($scope);` and inject `$compile`

Comment: @Tushar thanks a lot, it works. Can you please paste this as answer?

Comment: You're welcome. :) As the question is already answered and is dupe, nobody can answer a closed question. You can go and upvote the answers on the linked question.